# How to call parent touch event even if a child is inside it?

Tags: android

I have a linear layout and a button. I need to intercept parent touch listener even if i touch over/above the button.
Here is my code :-

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/button_privacy_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/wysiwyg_privacy_selector"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/ten"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/twenty"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/ten"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/ten" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonPrivacy"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_privacy"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Can i achieve it using xml by some property ?

Comment: no you cannot do that

Answer (score 0):

Try to `return false` in parent `onTouch` method for example:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //Some code
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set OnTouchListener for LinearLayout and return false in onTouch method

```
buttonPrivacyLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                            //buttonPrivacyLayout view was clicked
            return false;
        }
    });
```

If onTouch method return false, than button also can to handle OnTouchListener

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent2"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip" >

</LinearLayout>
```

and perform click of parent2 layout